# gem ''factory_girl_rails" Error uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

Here is my factories/admin_user.rb code

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin_user do |admin|
    admin.sequence(:email) { |n| "admin#{n}@example.com" }
    admin.password "123456789"
    admin.password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
  end
end
```

When I run this code I got this Error

> uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)

Any Help??

Comment: The "define" codes are not supposed to run directly. How do you use factory in test?

Comment: I am using like this FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user).should be_valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be gem not loaded. You can check if FactoryGirl is correctly defined in Gemfile. And also check if ENV is correct as FactoryGirl is supposed to run under Test env.

**Add**
Maybe test generator is not set correctly? You can check if you have put the following content in `config/application.rb`

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec,
  fixtures: true,
  view_specs: false,
  helper_specs: false,
  routing_specs: false,
  controller_specs: true,
  request_specs: true
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "spec/factories"
end
```

The last line about fixture should be important to your case. Then you can try to remove your hack setting.

Comment: I solved it by declaring require 'factory_girl_rails' in spec_helper.rb

Comment: Nice you fixed it. But that's weird, normally you don't need to do that. FactoryGirl will be loaded automatically with spec/factories.rb or spec/factories/blahblah.rb

Comment: @ChZeeshan, check my added part.